# What is a Target Attribute and what are values?

Tags: html

I'm stuck on step 14 on freecodecamp catphotoapp. There is normally an explanation on what it is, but it's asking me to add a target value with the value `_blank`.

Here's the example:

Add a target attribute with the value `_blank` to the anchor (a) element's opening tag, so that the link opens in a new tab.

```
<p>See more <a href="https://freecatphotoapp.com">cat photos</a> in our gallery.</p>
```

I'm not sure how to add the `target`.

Comment: Welcome! Google is your friend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a - There is a section about the `target` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can see examples of HTML attributes:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp

In your situation, you probably need to write

```
<a target="_blank">...</a>
```

so that the tag  - also known as the anchor tag - has an attribute `target` with a value `"_blank"`.

If the tag has other attributes already (like `href="https://www.google.com"` or `title="See this link"`) you can write them one after the other in any order like so:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" title="See this link" target="_blank">...</a>
```

Comment: Didn't see that you included the markup, but you will probably know what to do